# Addon-managers for .NET-applications?

Tags: .net, user-interface, scripting, add-on

Is there any addon-manager for .NET-applications? I would like to build the "core" of my program with C# or VB.Net and then be able to extend it using some kind of addon-manager/combined scripting and GUI.

Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/) (MEF) that is built to do this. MEF is available as part of .NET 4. From the CodePlex site:

The Managed Extensibility Framework simplifies the creation of extensible applications. MEF offers discovery and composition capabilities that you can leverage to load application extensions.

**What problems does MEF solve?**

MEF presents a simple solution for
   the runtime extensibility problem.
   Until now, any application that
   wanted to support a plugin model
   needed to create its own
   infrastructure from scratch. Those
   plugins would often be
   application-specific and could not be
   reused across multiple
   implementations.

- MEF provides a
  standard way for the host application
  to expose itself and consume external
  extensions. Extensions, by their
  nature, can be reused amongst
  different applications. However, an
  extension could still be implemented
  in a way that is
  application-specific. Extensions
  themselves can depend on one another
  and MEF will make sure they are wired
  together in the correct order
  (another thing you won't have to
  worry about).
- MEF offers a set of
  discovery approaches for your
  application to locate and load
  available extensions.
- MEF allows
  tagging extensions with additonal
  metadata which facilitates rich
  querying and filtering